# What does MSE value indicate for the accuracy and performance of prediction models?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-science

I am getting Mean square error value as 6.2 after implementing linear regression and around 5.369 for Random Forests Regression. I am not able to draw a conclusion if this is a good value, indicator of something for the forecast models. What does this values indicate for the predictions or in terms of accuracy and performance of my model? Can someone point out if this is an acceptable value or the model needs to be refined?

Answer (score 0):

The error depends on the scale of your data.

It cannot be compared across different data, and there is no "default" of what is a good value. It depends on what an acceptable prognosis error is for *you*.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, I would say that you need to have a baseline to compare to your model. It is really important to be able to analyse your model preformance. The baseline could an acceptable prognosis error for you as said before or it could be the performance of a "random" classifier (for example in a classification task) or maybe it could be the performance of the "simplest" model you try (for example, the score of 6.2 could be the baseline to use to test other model)